# ¿Cómo puedo copiar ficheros conservando el árbol de directorios?

Tags: bash, unix, búsquedas

Quiero replicar un árbol de directorios en UNIX con Bash. Quiero hacerlo solo para aquellos directorios donde hay archivos csv y copiar estos. El directorio donde se encuentran y el de destino vienen dados como parámetros $1 y $2 respectivamente.

Por ahora tengo esto:

```
ts=$2
mkdir -p $ts

for file in $(find $1 -name '*.csv'); do

  fileinput=$file
  path=$ts'/'$(dirname "${fileinput}")

  mkdir -p $path
  mv $fileinput $path

done
```

Mueve todo bien y crea el árbol de esta forma

```
/Users/avazquez/Desktop/new//Users/avazquez/Desktop/old/as
```

donde  `/Users/avazquez/Desktop/old/marzo2018` es la ruta del .csv
y `/Users/avazquez/Desktop/new` es donde quiero ponerlo (en realidad en `/Users/avazquez/Desktop/new/marzo2018` ya que habrá otros en `new` y otros en `Abril 2018`...)

Pero como se puede ver me crea, entre la carpeta de destino y donde están los archivos, muchas subcarpetas enlazadas con el unico contenido de otra carpeta hasta llegar a donde están los archivos.

He probado sustituyendo cadenas, borrando pero siempre da errores. ¿Alquien puede ayudarme?

El script me funciona tanto en mac como en linux. $1 y $2 tienen las rutas absolutas, dónde esta la carpeta raiz de los archivos csv y dónde los quiero guardar respectivamente, en este caso: `/Users/avazquez/Desktop/old` y `/Users/avazquez/Desktop/new/`.

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde Stack Overflow o accediste directamente a Stack Overflow en español? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y sería útil saber el motivo, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara, explicitando que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.

Comment: Casi siempre que busco información me aparece en inglés y creía que sería más facil entontrar respuesta así. Para preguntar he accedido desde google y no me he fijado que estaba en el sitio en español.

Comment: Dónde ejecutas el script? Y con qué parámetros? El $1 y el $2 qué tienen?

Comment: el script me funciona tanto en mac como en linux. $1 y $2 tienen las rutas absolutas, dónde esta la carpeta raiz de los archivos csv y dónde los quiero guardar respectivamente, en este caso: /Users/avazquez/Desktop/old y /Users/avazquez/Desktop/new/

Answer (score 1):

Estás creando directorios dentro del for con el path al fichero cvs encontrado.

Deberías hacer algo similar a:

```
ts=$2
mkdir -p $ts
cd $1

for file in $(find . -name '*.csv'); do

  fileinput=$file
  path=$ts'/'$(dirname "${fileinput}")
  mkdir -p $path
  mv $fileinput $path

done
```

Es decir, cambia de directorio dentro del script, y así dirname te devolverá el path relativo, al hacer find desde ".".

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás complicando el tema al utilizar un bucle para algo que `for` sabe hacer solito con:

```
cd "$1"  # es decir, va a tu directorio de origen
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec cp --parents \{\} "$2" \;  # copia en el directorio de destino
```

Idea tomada de [Copy specific file type keeping the folder structure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107647/40596).

Veámoslo con un ejemplo: creo una estructura de directorios y ficheros como esta.

```
$ find ddd -type f
ddd/d1/bla.csv
ddd/d1/d2/bla.csv
ddd/d1/d2/bla.ea
ddd/d2/bla.csv
```

Ahora quiero copiar los ficheros CSV. En particular, estaré buscando los directorios donde haya este tipo de ficheros, que es lo que en el fondo quieres hacer. Entonces diciendo esto ya lo tengo:

```
$ find -name '*csv' -type f
./ddd/d1/bla.csv
./ddd/d1/d2/bla.csv
./ddd/d2/bla.csv
```

Ahora es solo cuestión de especificar qué hacer con cada uno de los resultados, y allí es donde entra `--exec` en acción: le decimos que copie el fichero junto con toda su jerarquía (de ahí el `--parents`) y que lo haga en el directorio de destino.

Para evitar que `find` devuelva las rutas absolutas, lo que hacemos es un `cd "tu_directorio"` (`$1`, de hecho).